# AWS PHP SDK deleteMatchingObjects() does not return count

Tags: php, cakephp, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The AWS PHP SDK documentation for deleteMatchingObjects states that it returns an integer: "Returns the number of deleted keys"

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_deleteMatchingObjects

My media is deleted successfully but I get an empty value back where I'm supposed to get a count of deleted objects. Am I doing something wrong?

This is in the beforeDelete method of a CakePHP 2.x Model Behavior.

```
$s3 = new Aws\Sdk(array('version' => 'latest', 'region'  => 'us-west-1', 'credentials' => array('key' => $this->s3Key, 'secret' => $this->s3Secret)));
$client = $s3->createS3();
$delete = $client->deleteMatchingObjects($this->s3ReadBucket, $this->fileGroupPrefix($model->name, $model->id));
$this->__logger($delete);
```

Comment: 2022 and it still true...